# Create three-color gradient like Illustrator color picker

Tags: color, gradient

**Problem:**

I am having difficulties figuring out how to create a three-color gradient (white, black and blue) like the one used in Illustrator's color picker (left color box).

**Example #1 (how it should be):**
[image]
**Example #2 (how it is now):**
[image]
**Desired output:**

To get the gradient in three colors with white on the top-left corner, black below, and blue in the top-right corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Illustrator

1. Draw a white filled square
2. Use the Mesh tool (U) to select a corner
3. Double click on the fill colour icon, choose a colour from the colour picker
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each corner

Example

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.